# maven outputting lots of "FINE" log messages, how do I stop it?

Tags: maven, maven-3

When I run maven I get output as if I had specified logging level FINE which makes it very hard to find the actual output.  I also get hundreds of lines listing the explicit and implicit bindings.  As far as I can tell I've not configured mvn at all.  I'm running from within a cygwin shell.

Here is a sample that also gives info about my version and such.

```
$ mvn --show-version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 03:44:56-0500)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_31, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Module execution: 344ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: TypeListeners & ProvisionListener creation: 6ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Scopes creation: 4ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Converters creation: 1ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Binding creation: 23ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Private environment creation: 1ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Injector construction: 0ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Binding initialization: 20ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Binding indexing: 1ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Collecting injection requests: 0ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Binding validation: 1ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Static validation: 0ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Instance member validation: 5ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Provider verification: 2ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM com.google.inject.internal.util.Stopwatch resetAndLog
FINE: Static member injection: 0ms
Jan 23, 2013 3:33:03 PM org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.Logs$JULSink debug
FINE: Add publisher: com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl@561777b1

-----[explicit bindings]-------------------------------------------------------
0. ProviderInstanceBinding{key=Key[type=com.google.inject.Injector, annotation=[none]], source=[unknown source], scope=Scopes.NO_SCOPE, provider=Provider<Injector>}
1. ProviderInstanceBinding{key=Key[type=java.util.logging.Logger, annotation=[none]], source=[unknown source], scope=Scopes.NO_SCOPE, provider=Provider<Logger>}
2. InstanceBinding{key=Key[type=com.google.inject.Stage, annotation=[none]], source=[unknown source], instance=DEVELOPMENT}
.
.
.
194. ConstructorBinding{key=Key[type=org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.ThreadConfigurationService, annotation=[none]], source=ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null], scope=Scopes.SINGLETON}
195. ConstructorBinding{key=Key[type=org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor, annotation=[none]], source=ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null], scope=Scopes.SINGLETON}
196. ConstructorBinding{key=Key[type=org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleThreadedBuilder, annotation=[none]], source=ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null], scope=Scopes.SINGLETON}
197. ConstructorBinding{key=Key[type=org.apache.maven.lifecycle.Lifecycle, annotation=[none]], source=ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null], scope=Scopes.SINGLETON}
```

Comment: Check your environment variables for settings which might affect logging and your classpath for log configuration files which might override Maven's default settings.

Comment: I've looked but see no environment variables having to do with logging.  I also don't have a classpath variable set.  Inside the mvn command I can see MAVEN_OPTS isn't set, I'm pointing to a stock JVM installation.  So I'm still puzzled how this vanilla installation thinks I want all this logging :-)

Comment: Have you tried executing `mvn --show-version` in directory which doesn't contain a pom.xml file? In case the problem is with your project :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that my JAVA_HOME was pointing at a JDK installation rather than a JRE install...which makes no sense to me but it now works.

I edited the mvn command script to echo where it was running java from.  When running from
 .../Java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin I would get all of these errors but when running from 
 .../Java/jre6/bin I would not.

I guess the jdk assuming more debugging...or something?  I've never seen behavior like this before.

Comment: can you check the logging.properties within your JDK still, to find the root cause?

Comment: Interesting.  By setting my M2_HOME directory and JAVA_HOME directories, this seems to go away.    I still had trouble reproducing originally where the overlogging originally came from though... certainly that level of fine logging shouldnt be a default for any system .

Answer (score 3):

It looks more like log output than anything generated by Maven.  Looking at the source code for the [Stopwatch class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jolira/guice/2.1.8/com/google/inject/internal/util/Stopwatch.java#Stopwatch.resetAndLog%28java.lang.String%29), it's using Java Util Logging.  Have you set the default logging properties to include the FINE level of output?  This could be in the JAVA_HOME itself.

But, this is more how you have logging configured than anything Maven's doing

Answer (score 2):

Can you check for a file `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/logging.properties` under your JDK folder? guice within maven uses java.util.logging, and if you have file like that specified, it can turn on logger or loggers using java.util.logging.

Answer (score 0):

Since `--show-version` is documented to

> Display version information WITHOUT stopping build

I believe that this information somehow comes from a pom.xml file, a misconfigured settings.xml file or a debug setting places inside `MAVEN_HOME`.